# In C# how to handle an invalid argument type exception before it occurs?

Tags: c#

In C# how to handle an invalid argument type exception before it occurs

```
 static class calc
 {
    public static double subtract(double num1, double num2)
    {
        // I want to handle arguments exception here so whenever a nethod is called I can handle the exception

        return num1 - num2;
    }
  }
```

I want to handle exception if the user use wrong arguments' type.

Comment: the compiler won't accept to compile if the arguments are not double or implicitely convertible to double. Or did I misunderstood you ?

Comment: It depends on what's going on in that method that could possibly throw such an exception. Currently there is no way such an exception can happen.

Comment: @Steve this is true however what i wanted is to create my personal exceptions for my class so when somebody access my class he will get my special exception message, but i think it is not possible thanks to all of you

Answer (score 4):

In the case of your example, how could the arguments be invalid? Since you state the types, the values cannot be invalid.

The only scenario I can think of is if the `(num1 - num2) < Double.MinValue` in which case this would cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

verify that the parameters you are passing are actually valid types BEFORE you call the method.

Alternatively, Catch the exception using a try and catch around the call.

```
    try 
    {
         //Call Method
         subtract(1.0,2.0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
       // Or display a message box.  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see for this method to fail would be :

1) You call this method by reflection, but with bad parameters. This wouldn't be an argument exception since the problem would be "outside the call".

2) You call the function with such parameters that `double` - `double` != `double`. This wouldn't be exception ***if the user use wrong arguments' type*** though. For this, you can check your argument against `double.Min` :

```
static class calc
{
    public static double subtract(double num1, double num2)
    {
        double doubleAmountLeft = double.MaxValue - num1;
        if (num2 > num1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("num2 > double.MaxValue - num1.");
        }

        return num1 - num2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like, for example, this?

```
 static class calc
 {
    public static double subtract(double num1, double num2)
    {
        if (num1<num2) throw new ArgumentException("num1 < num2", "num2");
        return num1 - num2;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't even compile this as accepting something that isn't double or can be converted to double. However, since compiling may happen close to execution (e.g. when the calling code is in an .aspx file), there is a bit of a point to this *sometimes*. It can also be convenient in such cases to have a form that accepts `object` parameters anyway so that the casting with the results of `DataBinder.Eval` doesn't have to be done on-page:

```
static class Calc
{
  public static double Subtract(double num1, double num2)
  {
     return num1 - num2; //always correct type
  }
  public static double Substract(object num1, object num2)
  {
     try
     {
        return Subtract((double)num1, (double)num2);
        //alternatively allowing looser matching:
        //return Subtract(Convert.ToDouble(num1) - Convert.ToDouble(num2));
     }
     catch
     {
        throw new Exception("My Custom Exception Text");
     }
  }
}
```

Frankly though, I'd find this more confusing than the default behaviour if I pass the wrong type from on-the-fly compiled code like that in .aspx as I'd know the common exceptions better than yours.